# Null pointer exception when parsing XML

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, xml, dom

```
DOM.Document xmlDOC = new DOM.Document();
xmlDOC.load(xmlstring); 
DOM.XMLNode rootElement = xmlDOC.getRootElement();
for(DOM.XMLNode xmlnodeobj:xmlDOC.getRootElement().getChildElements()){
    For(Quote_line_item__c q:q1){   
        if(q.Name==xmlnodeobj.getChildElement('REF',null).getText()){
            q.Current_Stock__c= xmlnodeobj.getChildElement('QUANTITY',null).getText();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample XML string:

```
XMLString='<RESULT><LINE><REF>12600</REF><QUANTITY>980</QUANTITY></LINE><LINE><REF>12601</REF><QUANTITY>3254</QUANTITY></LINE></RESULT>';
```

Exception : Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
>   Class.createorder.: line 128, column 1
>   **xmlnodeobj.getChildElement('REF',null).getText()**

Null pointer exception coming from this statement.

Can any body help me regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you should check for `NULL` condition as:

```
   DOM.Document xmlDOC = new DOM.Document(); 
   xmlDOC.load(xmlstring); 
   DOM.XMLNode rootElement = xmlDOC.getRootElement();
   for(DOM.XMLNode xmlnodeobj:xmlDOC.getRootElement().getChildElements()){
    if(xmlnodeobj.getChildElement('REF',null) != null) // CHECK FOR NULL
      for(Quote_line_item__c q:q1){   
        if(q.Name==xmlnodeobj.getChildElement('REF',null).getText()){
          q.Current_Stock__c=     xmlnodeobj.getChildElement('QUANTITY',null).getText();

      }
    }
   }
```

it seems like you are skipping `<LINE>` and trying to parse directly `REF`.

Comment: i am passing 4 set i am getting result for only first set  q.Current_Stock__c

Comment: Can you post the updated code? @KarthikaRam